# PHP: using setcookie at the beginning of AJAX request does not save cookie post-request?

Tags: php, cookies

whenever the ajax page is called, i run:

```
setcookie($filtersCookie, $cookieVal, time() + 86400); // 1 day
```

and when the page is refreshed, i use the following code to see if there were any past filters saved:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE[$filtersCookie])) {
```

but the cookie never exists after a page refresh. any ideas as to why this may happen?

setcookie is used before any browser output from the ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Ajax scripts resides in another directory than the calling page, then you should also use the `path` parameter

```
setcookie($filtersCookie, $cookieVal, time() + 86400, "/"); // 1 day
```

By default the cookie will be available from the directory the cookie is set on, using "/" will make it available to all paths.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think the browser will intercept the cookie when ajax call. You can do a work around like setting the cookie from javascript.